Orchestrating Events & Third Party Services
I am developing a hobby project utilizing an event sourced + event based architecture. In this application, I can allow my users to schedule automated calls in the system. Once the call has been done using some 3rd party service (think Twilio or etc), I'll likely want to emit an event like "CallCompletedEvent" and do some state updates. But I'm struggling to understand when I should emit this event in a manner in which I can guarantee that I only trigger the Twilio API once. My problem is that any one of these two (3rd party service & my eventstore) may be offline and I can't be able to guarantee delivery to both.
Generally when trying to coordinate database entries and event emission, we use the Outbox pattern to guarantee delivery after persistence. But in my case, I don't know what to do.

Are you across the term "eventual consistency" and what it entails? Exactly once delivery is generally speaking a pipedream, you tend to have to pick between "risk sending it twice" or "risk not sending it at all". Which is best is a subjective call and highly contextual.

It may come down to that. I just was not sure @Flater

... in which I can guarantee that I only trigger the API once  =>   the State design pattern guarantees, through defined transitions only, a given state and thus any associated event triggers.


I'm struggling to understand when I should emit this event in a manner in which I can guarantee that I only trigger the Twilio API once.

In the general case, "exactly once" is not one of your choices when interacting with another system across an unrealiable network.  Instead, you get to choose between "at most once" (you make a best effort one time, and live with the outcome of that) or "at least once" (you keep trying until you get a response, and then judge what to do).
Note: one of the reasons that "idempotent" semantics are important in an API is that the semantic guarantees allow a remote client to send multiple copies of "the same" message without unintended consequences.
Given that our hypothetical 3rd party may be "offline" at any given moment, that normally means that in our service we need a two step process, where we "now" insert into an "always available queue" the information we need to send the message, and a separate process that will attempt to drain that queue when the third party is available.
[Note: I'm using "queue" here as a sort of idealized approximation of the idea - think "to do list"; but be aware that real queues can also bring in a bunch of complexity: ex: Dziuba 2011).]
Often this means that the message in the queue will need to have a bunch of metadata available so that you can later join the work done contacting the 3rd party API to the rest of the work.
Note that this doesn't really "solve" the exactly-once problem; it just defers the problems to a later time, and allows us to effectively isolate all of the realiable-communication-with-third-party bother into a dedicated module.
(The broad problem, in the general case, is that we cannot readily distinguish sent requests that get lost on the way to the 3rd party, and sent responses that get lost on the way from the 3rd party.  In addition, we can't readily distinguish messages which are lost from messages which are merely delayed.)
Building out a robust/resilient solution often means incorporating into the system affordances for compensation, when the Right Thing[tm] doesn't happen the first time.
